Can someone help me find a post of mine about super or sub?
I remember having asked a question about super or sub. But I can't find it. I don't have enough reputations (2k) for searching in deleted posts. Can someone help me find the link to the post?

Can you see this page?
It lists your deleted questions, but I can't tell for sure whether you have access to it.
Judging by the titles, you don't seem to have a deleted question about super or sub.
